# Laravel carbon group by time period

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am trying to make an archive with Laravel where I can store written articles. I want this to have a structure like:

```
 - Today
   - Article 1
 - This week
   - Article 2
   - article 3
 - This month
   - Article 4
 - This year
   - Article 4
```

And when there are no articles in, for example "Today", the title "Today" is not shown. Same for any other category.

I managed to make an archive where I could store articles within a specific format, like per year:

```
$archives = Article::all()->groupBy(function($date) {
      return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y');
});
```

[image: As-is]

but is it possible to achive the list I gave above with some changes to the code I have now or with some other code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using MySQL, we can make it fairly elegant (although it does require a `DB::raw()`).  Also it's pretty easy to make changes to.

```
$groupSelect =
"CASE
    WHEN DAYOFYEAR(created_at) = DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) THEN 'Today'
    WHEN WEEKOFYEAR(created_at) = WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE()) THEN 'This Week'
    WHEN DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m') THEN 'This Month'
    WHEN YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURDATE()) THEN 'This Year'
    ELSE 'Super Duper Long Time Ago'
END AS theGroup";

$archives = Article::select('*')->addSelect(DB::raw($groupSelect))->get()->groupBy(function($article) {
    return $article->theGroup;
});
```

If you don't like the raw SQL you can add a function to your `Article` model which will read the date and determine if it's Today, This Week, This Month, or This Year and returns that string...

```
public function getDiffForArchive()
{
    if ( strtotime($this->attributes['created_at']) > strtotime('-1 day')) {
        return 'Today';
    } else if (...) {  // Continue on with above logic.
        return '...';
    }
}
```

Then in your callback it's as simple as...

```
return $article->getDiffForArchive();
```

#### Edit

I've updated the SQL because I think it's close to what you want and also needed to start with `select('*)` on your query builder, otherwise it will only select the `theGroup`.  It works now though, I've tested it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: But `$archives` doesn't return a collection of Article instances (I can't access the methods and properties (the only property is `theGroup`))

Comment: Sorry, not sure why, you need to select * as well.  I'll update my answer.